# NFOP performance problem

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

We're using NFOP in a project (C#, ASP.NET 2.0) to ultimately return PDF files to the user.

The process currently goes like this:

1. Stored Procedure -> XML
2. XML -> XSLT -> XSL-FO
3. XSL-FO -> NFOP -> PDF

This works fine, the PDF is generated BEAUTIFULLY.  The problem is that it takes 300+ seconds to do it.  The ANTS profiler indicates that the problem is sitting in the

```
driver.run()
```

method inside of NFOP.  It's not like this is a gargantuan amount of data, the size of the xsl-fo source going into the nfop driver object is ~980k.  What's the most likely source and resolution of this problem?

**ANY** hints or tips or answers are most appreciated, we were supposed to head to VA scan at 11 am.  :|

Answer (score 1):

have you considered FO.NET?

Comment: No, we'll take a look at that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a freely available tool like [VisualVM](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) and profile your code. It can show you the problem quite fast.

Comment: Please see the question.  We HAVE used a profiler.  It doesn't tell us anything useful.  This is why I've asked the question here.

Comment: A profiler will 'drill down' into driver.run(). Try a commercial one if VisualVM does not have what it takes.